# How to / Can I Request Work Documents from Competitor Companys

Tags: work-experience, documentation

In order to manage my work perfectly and add something new or rectify some faults, I want to compare my job with other concurrent companies by requesting work documents (any available form and file format).

Can I request work documents from people in other companies (Concurrent of course), is this legal or just it is dumb idea ?

Comment: What "work documents"? What is a "concurrent" company

Comment: "work documents" = any (Excel, Word, Pdf, Print, Scan...) document similar to your work in a (concurrent = different company in the same sector).

Comment: What specific documents do you have in mind? Position descriptions for positions that are similar to your position? Something else? Be specific about the data you are looking for: salary figures, for example, may be considered confidential information.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.  Do you want competitors to send you documents about how they do their work?

Comment: @jcm: Yes, it is the goal of the question, maybe to collaborate with each other.

Comment: @AbdelhafidMadoui You know what the road to hell is paved with, right? It's paved with good intentions. In your case, it would be the road to unemployment hell or worse, a pounding in court if your employer takes exception to what you are doing i.e. unauthorized sharing of confidential information. Even if that info is in plain sight on a company's website, you might still get in trouble with the company, depending upon the law in your country, if the company declares that info as confidential.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Can I request work documents from people in other companies
>   (Concurrent of course), is this legal or just it is dumb idea ?

You can request anything. But it isn't common for competitors to help each other get better.

And before you go sharing your own company's information with your competition, you had better make sure you have management's written approval. In my company, you'd be fired on the spot if you did that without prior approval. And I would never hire someone who shared his company secrets without approval.

Being known as someone who shares his company's work products can be a career-limiting move.

That said, some companies share industry knowledge with each other - in seminars, in industry forums, etc.

Ask around your company first. Get permission first. Then, and only then, proceed carefully.

Answer (score 1):

So you are trying to transfer knowledge from one company to another

Any you think the company you have left would be happy about that considering the two companies are competitors.

Now let me think

Comment: But look at the workers side also? I did not say: i stole it. I say: He gave me it.

Comment: @AbdelhafidMadoui breaking a number of employment laws in process as well as being very unprofessional

Comment: @AbdelhafidMadoui - So you are saying you got a job in your previous company competitors. You are going to ask them "please give us the IP that we paid for". They are going to say "Sure - here is my shirt as well"

Comment: Boys and Girls - Do not employ this person. He is likely to go back to the first company.